# How to access Mongo Collection by name on Meteor server-side

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am unable to find a way to access Meteor Mongo Collections server-side.
From the client, I can iterate over each collection and remove specific entries:

`_.forIn(global, (value, key) => {
    if (!!value && value instanceof Mongo.Collection && !!value._connection) {                  Meteor.connection._stores[value._name]._getCollection().remove({ owner: userId }); // Work client side only
    }
});`

Comment: Easy and safe tool that solves this issue is `dburles:mongo-collection-instances` that allows you to get collections by name.

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I was looking for!